# The URL bar has vanished from Vivaldi browser

Tags: browser, vivaldi

Suddenly (probably after playing around with Vivaldi's full-screen view mode), the address bar (location bar or URL bar) has vanished from the Vivaldi browser!

Of course, I've clicked the "Reset address bar" button in SETTINGS:

[image]

Of course, I've also made sure the address bar is activated in SETTINGS:

[image]

But the address bar is still hidden!

This is my version of Vivaldi: 2.11.1811.38 (Stable channel) (64-Bit)

My Windows version is Windows 10 Home 64-bit 1909

Comment: Is it safe to uninstall and then reinstall Vivaldi, or would I lose my tabs or my bookmarks or anything other?

Comment: F8 also allows you to show a FLOATING address bar. But that cannot be set to a fixed address bar. Had to go through all this pain today again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be stuck in app mode, which does not work in Vivaldi. The only way I know to correct that is to refresh your profile.

Reinstalling Vivaldi to fix a problem is almost never necessary, and almost never helpful. It may happen, however, that some of your user files get into conflict with each other or the program, or become corrupt. You can "reset" Vivaldi to "factory condition" in such a case. We call this a refresh or a cleaning of your profile.

Occasionally a moderator or a user may recommend that you "refresh" or "clean" your profile to see if it will fix a problem. One way to do this without losing all of your user data, is as follows:

Make sure your system is set to display Hidden files.

1. Open Vivaldi and access the Main Menu (the "V" button at the top left or the horizontal menu at top if you have elected to show the menu that way), going to Help > About (or by typing vivaldi://about into the address bar).
2. In the resulting window, you will see an item labeled Profile Path. This tells you where your Default folder is. Default is the folder we will be working with. Note where it is.
3. Close Vivaldi and go to the folder on your hard drive that contains your Default folder. Rename the Default folder. You may name it anything you like, even Bernice.
4. Re-open Vivaldi, and test whether the problem is fixed. You will notice that all of your settings and data have disappeared. Have no fear.
5. If the problem is fixed, close Vivaldi again and go back to the folder that contains your old, renamed profile, plus your shiny brand new Default folder that Vivaldi made when you restarted it. Move critical data such as Bookmarks, Favicons, Login Data, history, cookies, etc. from Bernice to Default (check the "Back up some Vivaldi information" section in this article). You may even move the Top Sites file over, if you aren't keen to re-fetch all of your Speed Dial Thumbnails, etc., but old, over-sized Top Sites files have sometimes been implicated in slow running and high resource usage. DO NOT restore your Extensions files and folders. They are frequently the cause of the original problem you had.
6. Open Vivaldi and pick the settings and appearance you like. Re-install your extensions, one at a time, testing after each to ensure that a given extension doesn't break Vivaldi again. If it does, uninstall it and don't use it again.

And there you are! A fresh, clean copy of Vivaldi, good as new, and working correctly. Now you can save Bernice for a while to make sure she's not holding some forgotten data you needed, or you can delete her. She's fulfilled her purpose. Enjoy your new browsing experience!

Source: https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/10388/refreshing-or-cleaning-your-profile/1?lang=en-US

I also found several mini solutions in this thread. You may try to take a look.

https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/25504/address-bar-and-toolbars-missing/14

Comment: That was a lot of work, but at the end it worked: The address bar is visible again! It came out that "Current Session" was the file which contained the HideAddressBar setting. Now I still have to reinstall the Extensions.

Comment: Glad that one of these methods work for you.

Answer (score 4):

as I see it, you might have occasionally clicked Window -> Hide UI (Ctrl+F11) instead of Window -> Full screen (F11)
Those are the options that are next to each other in the menu, [see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEYSQ.png).

This was my case, when I clicked Hide UI again, I got my address bar back)))

So, you probably don't need to reset your profile ^)

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

This is what did it for me when the settings controls didn't work.

It wasn't easy to browse and just see that keyboard shortcut either